# Excel functions to covert X days, x hours, X minutes in actual minutes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've some data in excel in the following manner.

- 9 hours 16 minutes 2 seconds
- 4 days 7 hours 41 minutes 44 seconds
- 1 day 8 hours 3 minutes 49 seconds
- 33 minutes 4 seconds

I need to convert the data in the minute's format. I tried excel's find, left, right, mid functions but couldn't able to fetch the desired result.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are these text, or actual times that are formatted?

Comment: also, what do you want to do with seconds?  Round, truncate, or convert to decimal?

Comment: We can mitigate the seconds part but the prime motto is to get the minute's count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following array formula:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($1:$4)-1)*2*999+1,999))*CHOOSE(MATCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($1:$4)-1)*2*999+999,999))&"*",{"days","hours","minutes","seconds"},0),(60*24),60,1,(1/60)),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.

[image]

Comment: ...............................Beautiful !...............................